# How to convert base64 string to pdf and open with pdf viewer without saving it?

Tags: android, pdf

On button click, I want to convert base64 string to pdf file and then, open it with pdf viewer on android.

Following code is converting and saving pdf file. But, i don't want to save file. Should I save , open and delete file? or is there another way.

Thanks,

```
final File dwldsPath = new File(DOWNLOADS_FOLDER + fileName + ".pdf");
byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(txt, 0);
FileOutputStream os;
os = new FileOutputStream(dwldsPath, false);
os.write(pdfAsBytes);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Comment: You can create a temporary file by File.createTempFile() DId you tried this?